# CSRF token in Express with session disabled (REST)

Tags: node.js, rest, session, express, csrf

I am trying to implement CSRF protection in my `express` application. The application is meant to be RESTfull, so I am not using session.

I have tried to use `csurf` npm module but as far as I have understood this module's description, I need to use session. I might turn session on, but I think I should not do it since application should be RESTfull.

Is there any CSRF implementation for `express` that does not force developer to use session mechanism?

Comment: If you don't have sessions, how do you authenticate the sender of a request? Do you directly store credentials in a cookie? Or, if you don't authenticate the sender of a request, why do you need CSRF protection?

Comment: Good point. Since I am trying to create RESTfull app, I came up with Query Authentication. So CSRF is not needed anymore.